# In Flutter, how to disable scrolling of a child in TabBarView within NestedScrollView when its height is less than the screen？

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter, I have a `TabBarView` within a `NestedScrollView` with two children. The two children are scrollable, and are built with `FutureBuilder`, when there're data they return a `ListView`.

[image]

When there's no data, it'll fetch them from server, and return a `Text` with a notice "Nothing to show yet." before the data are loaded. However in this case, you can still scroll the blank part with only a `Text` even make it disappear into the top out of screen.

[image]

How to disable the scrolling when it's not necessary? Is it possible to make the `NestedScrollView` smart to decide weather to enable scroll itself, for example by comparing the children's Height and the Height of screen? Thanks!

Comment: Attach the FutureBuilder widget code too.

Comment: My codes of the `FutureBuilder` are very complex. I think it is kind of irrelevant to this issue. You can think of it as a `Text` within a `Container` when there's no local data. @KedarKarki

Answer (score 2):

You can do one thing, use [NeverScrollablePhysics property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NeverScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html) when there is no data in your `NestedScrollView`

**How?**

You can check whether there is some data or not, if not, make the physics `NeverScrollablePhysics` else [AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics-class.html#:%7E:text=Scroll%20physics%20that%20always%20lets,override%20the%20handling%20of%20overscrolling.&text=ScrollPhysics%2C%20which%20can%20be%20used,default%20behavior%20is%20desired%20instead.)

**Code**

```
// suppose your futurebuilder looks like this
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: your_future, 
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot){
     NestedScrollView(
       // if the snapshot has some data, then scrollable else not a scrollable widget
       physics: snapshot.hasData ? AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics() : NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
     )
  }
)
```

**OR**

You can do one thing, use [primary property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView/primary.html) inside your `ListView` or whatever view you are using. **Do this primary: false**. What it will do is to tell the widget that it is not primary and hence can only be taken into consideration when they reach to the bottom and some more data is pending to be shown.

Comment: My structure is a lot more complex, with `FutureBuilder` for each child and children's children have their own `FutureBuilder` too. Though can't solve it simply in your way, I get your idea, thank you. Is it possible to make the `NestedScrollView` smart to decide weather to enable scroll itself, for example by comparing the children's Height and the Height of screen?

Comment: I am not sure whether you can use `primary` in the `NestedScrollView `, but you can definitely use in the `ListView`. Use `primary: false`, and it will work fine @ArtS

Answer (score 2):

I've found the key is not about scrolling, it is the `SliverAppBar` covering the top part of the `TabBarView`. A solution is to use `SliverOverlapAbsorber` with a `SliverSafeArea`, with the help from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27906#issuecomment-499043685

Sample codes:

```
                        SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                          handle:
                              NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(
                                  context),
                          sliver: SliverSafeArea(
                            sliver: SliverAppBar(
                              floating: true,
                              pinned: true,
                              bottom: TabBar(
                                tabs: [
                                  Tab(text: "Posts"),
                                  Tab(text: "Likes"),
                                ],
                              ),
                              expandedHeight: 450,
                              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                                collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
                                background: Scaffold(
                                  body: Container(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
```